# Makefile, how to link conflicting 3rd party sources?

Tags: azure, makefile, iot, stm32ldiscovery

Please help me create a proper Makefile.

I'm trying to compile a STM32L4 Discovery Azure demo fw using gcc-arm-none-eabi on linux. I took a Makefile generated with STM32CubeMX and populated it with files and settings from the kiel project file (.uvprojx). Unfortunately the result terminates with an linking error. After some digging and a dirty patch, I was able to get the Makefile to run without error. Still my goal is to create a proper Makefile. How do I keep 3rd party codes from conflicting during linking?

```
C_SOURCE = \
...
Src/azure_base64.c \
Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/library/base64.c
```

`Src/azure_base64.c` looks to be just a wrapper

```
#Include "../Middlewares/Third_Party/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/base64.c"
```

https://github.com/acornblue/AZURE_LAB

```
Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/Makefile
Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/MDK-ARM/B-L475E-IOT01/Project.uvprojx
```

Linking error -

```
build/base64.o: In function `Base64_Decoder': /home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/base64.c:188: multiple definition of `Base64_Decoder'
build/azure_base64.o:/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/Src/../../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/base64.c:188: first defined here
build/base64.o: In function `base64char': /home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/base64.c:19: multiple definition of `Base64_Encode_Bytes'
build/azure_base64.o:/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/Src/../../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/base64.c:19: first defined here 
build/base64.o: In function `base64char': /home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/base64.c:19: multiple definition of `Base64_Encoder'
build/azure_base64.o:/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/Src/../../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/base64.c:19: first defined here
build/sha1.o: In function `SHA1Reset':/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/sha1.c:84: multiple definition of `SHA1Reset'
build/azure_sha1.o:/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/Src/../../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/sha1.c:84: first defined here
build/sha1.o: In function `SHA1ProcessMessageBlock':/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/sha1.c:366: multiple definition of `SHA1Input'
build/azure_sha1.o:/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/Src/../../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/sha1.c:366: first defined here
build/sha1.o: In function `SHA1ProcessMessageBlock':/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/sha1.c:366: multiple definition of `SHA1FinalBits'
build/azure_sha1.o:/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/Src/../../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/sha1.c:366: first defined here
build/sha1.o: In function `SHA1ProcessMessageBlock':/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/sha1.c:366: multiple definition of `SHA1Result'
build/azure_sha1.o:/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/Src/../../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/Azure-IoT-SDK-C/c-utility/src/sha1.c:366: first defined here
build/md_wrap.o: In function `sha1_process_wrap':/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/mbedtls/library/md_wrap.c:364: undefined reference to `mbedtls_sha1_process'
build/md_wrap.o: In function `sha1_clone_wrap':/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/mbedtls/library/md_wrap.c:352: undefined reference to `mbedtls_sha1_clone'
build/md_wrap.o: In function `sha1_ctx_free':/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/mbedtls/library/md_wrap.c:358: undefined reference to `mbedtls_sha1_free'
build/md_wrap.o: In function `sha1_ctx_alloc':/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/mbedtls/library/md_wrap.c:345: undefined reference to `mbedtls_sha1_init'
build/md_wrap.o: In function `sha1_finish_wrap':/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/mbedtls/library/md_wrap.c:337: undefined reference to `mbedtls_sha1_finish'
build/md_wrap.o: In function `sha1_update_wrap':/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/mbedtls/library/md_wrap.c:332: undefined reference to `mbedtls_sha1_update'
build/md_wrap.o: In function `sha1_starts_wrap':/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/mbedtls/library/md_wrap.c:326: undefined reference to `mbedtls_sha1_starts'
build/md_wrap.o: (.rodata.mbedtls_sha1_info+0x1c): undefined reference to `mbedtls_sha1'
build/pem.o: In function `mbedtls_pem_read_buffer':/home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/mbedtls/library/pem.c:322: undefined reference to `mbedtls_base64_decode' /home/mxuser/projects/AZURE_LAB/Projects/Multi/Applications/Azure_Sns_DM/../../../../Middlewares/Third_Parties/mbedtls/library/pem.c:330: undefined reference to `mbedtls_base64_decode'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: It looks like your makefile tries to link the object files of both the wrappers `azure_XXXX.o` AND the files which were textually included in these wrappers `XXXX.o` (e.g. `sha1`). Textual inclusion of a C file is _very_ uncommon for production code - the only times I do this is when  doing white box testing and I need to access `static` symbols in a non-intrusive way (i.e. without cluttering the production code with debug code). The other occasion where this is an acceptable technique is when one needs to integrate some really badly platform dependant code on another platform.

Comment: Yeah, its interesting that the file name stays despite the textual include. When I prepend 1 set of files,ie abase64 and asha1 the link will complete without error. Kiel doesn't seem to have any issue. So I wonder if there is something I'm not doing correctly in Makefile. FYI, there is only 1 base64.o and 1 azure_base64.o file.

Comment: The link most likely completes because the renamed object files are then absent and no collision happens. Is this a library?